# Помогите составить регулярное выражение. Строка в которую входят цифры от 1 до 12 разделенные ","

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Например есть строка: "1, 12, строка, 12" - как отловить слово "строка", и сделать, чтобы пользователь не ввел числа или другие слова, знаки, кроме 1-12, и ",".

А куда мне вставить алерт, чтобы уведомить пользователя, что он не верно ввел данные, например слово?

Comment: видимо где то так

    \d+(\s*,\s*\d+)+

Comment: > А куда мне вставить алерт, чтобы уведомить пользователя, что он неверно ввел данные, например слово?

Хорошим тоном будет подсветить инпут красненьким и вывести небольшой хинт рядом.

Comment: Извините, впервые здесь)

var str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12" - правильная строка var str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10" - правильная строка var str = "1, 2, 13, 4, 5, 9, 10" - неправильная строка, есть число > 12 var str = "1, 2, текст, 4, 5, 9, 10" - неправильная строка, содержит слово

Comment: function Control ()
{
var str = document.getElementById("Field");
var re = /([1-9]|1[0-2])$/;
if (str != null)
  {
      if (str.search(re) != -1)
      {
      alert ("Корректные данные");
      }
         else
         { 
     alert ("Некоректные данные!");
          }
}
 else {}
}

Answer (score 1):

А почему обязательно регулярка? Вам надо определить числа — вот и делайте честно, с числами.

Разбейте по запятой, распарсьте.

```
return s.split(",")
        .map(function(l){ return parseInt(l, 10); })
        .every(function(n) { return !isNaN(n) && 0 < n && n < 13; });
```

[Проверка](http://jsfiddle.net/q6cWe/).

Answer (score 0):

```
"0, 1, 12, строка, 12,13,14".split(/\s*,\s*/).filter(function (item) { return /^([1-9]|1[0-2])$/.test(item); }).join(", ")
// returns: "1, 12, 12"
```